# Can't see the item that I am dragging using React-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

So basically, everything works fine when I am using html5 backend, but since my app is going to be used on phones as well, I needed to switch to touch backend. And when I do, everything works fine except that I don't see items that I am dragging. Drop area accepts the items, changes the class and everything, but I just can't see the bloody thing, not on pc and not on mobile. I tried using DragPreviewImage and it works when switching to html5backend but no on touch.

Drag Component:

```
const [{isDragging}, drag] = useDrag({
    item: {
        type:ItemTypes.CARD,
        name: props.person,
        id: props.id
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
        isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
      }),
})


return (
    <div
    ref={drag}
    className={`${props.classNameToDisplay} ${isDragging ? 'onDrag' : ""}`}
    id={props.id}
    key={props.person}
    onClick={(e) => props.itemOnClick(e, props.person, props.itemClicked)}>
    {props.person}
</div>
);
```

Drop input component :

```
const DropInput = (props) => {

const[{isOver, canDrop}, drop] = useDrop({
    accept:ItemTypes.CARD,
    canDrop:(item, monitor) => true,
    drop: (item, monitor) => props.itemOnDrop(item,monitor, "regularBet", props.itemClicked),
    collect: monitor => ({
        isOver : !!monitor.isOver(),
        canDrop : !!monitor.canDrop()
    })
})

return (
    <input
    ref={drop}
    className={`${props.classNameToDisplay} ${isOver && canDrop ? 'onDropAllowed' : ''} `}
    onKeyUp={e => props.itemOnKeyUp(e, props.itemClicked)} 
    onChange={e => props.itemOnChange(e, 'name')}
    type="text"
    name={props.itemClicked}
    id={props.itemClicked}
    value={props.itemName}
    placeholder="ime"/>
);
```

Comment: Same here... I just opened an issue here: https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/2206

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: I duplicated my component, and used html5backend for when screen is bigger than 480px, and touchbackend for less. So at least now it works on computers, but still doesn't on the phones / touch.

Comment: @Pandaiolo see my answer. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending an hour or so trying to figure out this issue myself I found [react-dnd-preview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd-preview) which works for my situation. Hopefully this works for you too.

Comment: It worked for me too. It even says in documentation that touch-backend doesn't have ghost feature. "This project is a React component compatible with React DnD that can be used to emulate a Drag'n'Drop "ghost" when a Backend system doesn't have one (e.g. react-dnd-touch-backend)." Much appreciated man!

Comment: Unfortunately not currently compatible with React18